# In the Weeds on Pandas Multi-Indexing Using Slicers

Tags: python, pandas, slice, multi-index

I'm attempting to leverage the newly added ability in Pandas to access a multi-index using slicers but I'm having a bit of trouble with what seems to be a fairly straightforward slicing problem so just wanted to run it by the group here for some help.

The following is the code sample with a few examples that work and a few that don't:

```
import pandas as pd

# Displays: '0.14.1'
pd.__version__

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0'] * 5 + ['A1']*5 + ['A2']*5,
            'B': ['B0','B0','B1','B1','B2'] * 3,
            'DATE': ["2013-06-11",
                    "2013-07-02",
                    "2013-07-09",
                    "2013-07-30",
                    "2013-08-06",
                    "2013-06-11",
                    "2013-07-02",
                    "2013-07-09",
                    "2013-07-30",
                    "2013-08-06",
                    "2013-09-03",
                    "2013-10-01",
                    "2013-07-09",
                    "2013-08-06",
                    "2013-09-03"],
             'VALUES': [22, 35, 14,  9,  4, 40, 18, 4, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3,4, 2]})

df.DATE = df['DATE'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))

df1 = df.set_index(['A', 'B', 'DATE'])
df1 = df1.sortlevel()

df2 = df.set_index('DATE')

# A1 - Works - Get all values under "A0" and "A1"
df1.loc[(slice('A1')),:]

# A2 - Works - Get all values from the start to "A2"
df1.loc[(slice('A2')),:]

# A3 - Works - Get all values under "B1" or "B2"
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice('B1','B2')),:]

# A4 - Works - Get all values between 2013-07-02 and 2013-07-09
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),slice('20130702','20130709')),:]

##############################################
# These do not work and I'm wondering why... #
##############################################

# B1 - Does not work - Get all values in B0 that are also under A0, A1 and A2
df1.loc[(slice('A2'),slice('B0')),:]

# B2 - Does not work - Get all values in B0, B1 and B2 (similar to what #2 is doing for the As)
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice('B2')),:]

# B3 - Does not work - Get all values from B1 to B2 and up to 2013-08-06
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice('B1','B2'),slice('2013-08-06')),:]

# B4 - Does not work - Same as A4 but the start of the date slice is not a key.
#                      Would have thought the behavior would be similar to something like df2['20130701':]
#                      In other words, date indexing allowed starting on non-key points
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),slice('20130701','20130709')),:]
```

While there are certainly alternative simpler ways to get at the data, I'm hoping to be able to answer the specific example questions below in order to be able to use the knowledge as building blocks to do more complex multi-index slicing down the road.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: pls show pandas version; 0.14.1 fixed a couple of bugs in 0.14.0 for multi index slicers (and master a few more)

Comment: You might consider using the `idx = pd.IndexSlice` syntax to make these a bit easier to read.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#multiindexing-using-slicers

Comment: you also need to .sortlevel() or for sure multi level won't work - it's possible that it is not raising (and attempting to work even though it's not sorted - that might be a bug)

Comment: Sorry about that - just added a couple lines of code to show the version and sort the data frame.  I think I'm still getting the same error though even with the sorting (version is 0.14.1).  Just curious, does the example code work for you Jeff?  Thanks for the suggestion chrisb, will take a look at that now as well.

Comment: I'll have to look at these is more detail tomorrow - will let u know

Comment: these are buggy ATM, track this issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8132, as a work-around if you specifiy the start AND stop point this will work, e.g. ``slice('B0':'B3')``

Comment: fixed here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8134, will be merged in master soon. This was failing when the indexer was only 1 sided (e.g. slice('A2')) and not on 1st level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just merged into master/0.15.0, this PR http://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/8134 fixes the cases that were not working.

```
# A1 - Works - Get all values under "A0" and "A1"
df1.loc[(slice('A1')),:]

                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B0 2013-06-11      22
      2013-07-02      35
   B1 2013-07-09      14
      2013-07-30       9
   B2 2013-08-06       4
A1 B0 2013-06-11      40
      2013-07-02      18
   B1 2013-07-09       4
      2013-07-30       2
   B2 2013-08-06       5

# A2 - Works - Get all values from the start to "A2"
df1.loc[(slice('A2')),:]

                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B0 2013-06-11      22
      2013-07-02      35
   B1 2013-07-09      14
      2013-07-30       9
   B2 2013-08-06       4
A1 B0 2013-06-11      40
      2013-07-02      18
   B1 2013-07-09       4
      2013-07-30       2
   B2 2013-08-06       5
A2 B0 2013-09-03       1
      2013-10-01       2
   B1 2013-07-09       3
      2013-08-06       4
   B2 2013-09-03       2

# A3 - Works - Get all values under "B1" or "B2"
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice('B1','B2')),:]

                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B1 2013-07-09      14
      2013-07-30       9
   B2 2013-08-06       4
A1 B1 2013-07-09       4
      2013-07-30       2
   B2 2013-08-06       5
A2 B1 2013-07-09       3
      2013-08-06       4
   B2 2013-09-03       2

# A4 - Works - Get all values between 2013-07-02 and 2013-07-09
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),slice('20130702','20130709')),:]

                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B0 2013-07-02      35
   B1 2013-07-09      14
A1 B0 2013-07-02      18
   B1 2013-07-09       4
A2 B1 2013-07-09       3

# B1 -  Get all values in B0 that are also under A0, A1 and A2
df1.loc[(slice('A2'),slice('B0')),:]

                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B0 2013-06-11      22
      2013-07-02      35
A1 B0 2013-06-11      40
      2013-07-02      18
A2 B0 2013-09-03       1
      2013-10-01       2

# B2 - Get all values in B0, B1 and B2 (similar to what #2 is doing for the As)
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice('B2')),:]

                 VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B0 2013-06-11      22
      2013-07-02      35
   B1 2013-07-09      14
      2013-07-30       9
   B2 2013-08-06       4
A1 B0 2013-06-11      40
      2013-07-02      18
   B1 2013-07-09       4
      2013-07-30       2
   B2 2013-08-06       5
A2 B0 2013-09-03       1
      2013-10-01       2
   B1 2013-07-09       3
      2013-08-06       4
   B2 2013-09-03       2

# B3 - Get all values from B1 to B2 and up to 2013-08-06
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice('B1','B2'),slice('2013-08-06')),:]

                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B1 2013-07-09      14
      2013-07-30       9
   B2 2013-08-06       4
A1 B1 2013-07-09       4
      2013-07-30       2
   B2 2013-08-06       5
A2 B1 2013-07-09       3
      2013-08-06       4

# B4 - Same as A4 but the start of the date slice is not a key.
df1.loc[(slice(None),slice(None),slice('20130701','20130709')),:]
                  VALUES
A  B  DATE              
A0 B0 2013-07-02      35
   B1 2013-07-09      14
A1 B0 2013-07-02      18
   B1 2013-07-09       4
A2 B1 2013-07-09       3
```

Comment: Thanks for the fixes Jeff.  So this is a bit of a silly question, but now that the fix is in the repository, is the correct way to get access to it prior to the release of 0.15, to download the SVN code and build it myself?  So far my limited knowledge only knows how to double-click on an EXE.

Comment: I am guessing you are on windows. I normally post binaries http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-build/dev/. These are not updated to the latest (as their is an issue currently on this server). Check back soon.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeff - will keep checking your build site for the updated binary.  Hope you have a good Labor Day weekend (or just regular weekend if you're not in the US).

Comment: I just posted some windows binaries here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/releases (the 0.15pre) release.